# DTM: Implementing list variables

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

Does anybody knows how to implement the s.list variables in DTM.  I've added the following in the custom page code of an event, but nothing appears:

```
s.listTrackVars = "list2";
s.list2 = "widget";
```

Any recommendations on what I'm missing to make this work will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```js
s.listTrackVars = "list2";
```

Try

```js
s.linkTrackVars = "list2";
```